How to remove amazon variant from expo build
I'm working on an expo project someone created and set up long time ago. Every time I make a build with eas build --platform android --profile someprofile an archive with 2 apk variants is created: . How can I remove the amazon variant, please? The contents of the profile tell me nothing on the subject:
{
      "env": {
        "ENTRY_FILE": "./index.js"
      },
      "android": {
        "cache": {
          "disabled": true
        },
        "resourceClass": "large"
      },
      "expoCli": "6.3.10",
      "node": "20.5.0",
      "channel": "somechannel",
      "distribution": "internal"
    }

I tried googling, but in vain.
